# Which are the reliable ultrasonic sensors used in field?

Tags: ultrasonic, sensor

List the existing ultrasonic sensors used for bioacoustics work

Comment: Hi @Minu Merlin Sabu, this is a very broad question with a very large set of answers. Could you please rephrase the question to be more specific? Alternately you could make this question part of the communtyt wiki (see Meta discussion here and please do participate https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-to-decide-when-a-topic-question-should-be-made-into-a-community-wiki

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

The common commercially-available ultrasonic sensors I know of (for terrestrial work) are from the following companies:

https://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/products

https://www.titley-scientific.com/uk/

https://www.batlogger.com/en/

https://batsound.com/

https://www.batbox.com/

Hope that helps